Where should I post the questions/solutions that are related to Google Docs, Google Slides, Google Sheets, etc.?
I've posted this question along with the solution on Stack Overflow. But, it got downvoted, and showing "Not about programming or software development" in the Close reason.
So, where should I post this question and the corresponding solution?

[webapps.se] maybe? You should always read the site's tour before posting (something you're yet to do on [so] too). [webapps.se]'s tour states that you can ask questions about "Using a website which behaves like an application" which I would suggest Google Docs/Slides/etc are.

@ThomA to add to that, WebApps.SE does have tags for Google Docs, Google Slides, and Google Sheets

We all know that just because a tag exists doesn't mean it's on-topic, @VLAZ . ;) (Though, admittedly, with the smaller sites, it's less a problem.)

Yessir, I've posted there. Thanks.

If you really wanted to get meta, you can post questions about google docs to google docs.

Next time if you have a question that you really cannot figure out where to post after you've done your research, you can ask a question like this on [meta.se]
